# Parsing reply email to take only the latest part

Tags: java, parsing, jakarta-mail

In java mail, when i parse an replied email, how can I take only the latest message (the reply) and ignore the old ones?

Comment: With Javamail per se, can't do it, no... You'll have to parse the headers and build the logic to find that. Also, what it the thread forks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing the `<backquote> </backquote>` parts of the original email if it was received as an HTML email, and by removing lines beginning with `>` on text email.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about parsing the text content of the message to ignore the parts that are just previous messages that have been included in the response.

There's no well-defined way to do this.  You're going to need to apply some heuristics to try to guess which parts of the text are these "quoted" messages.  A common convention is that these messages are lines that start with ">", but that's not universal nor guaranteed.